# How can django dispatch visits to views based on domain

Tags: django, nginx, dns

For example, I have a django project, there are two pages.

*http://domain.com/A/things*

*http://domain.com/B/things*

Now I want that  visitors  can visits these pages with url

*http://A.domain.com/things*

*http://B.domain.com/things*

I tried to use nginx to rewrite the rule. Such as rewrite *"http://A.domain.com/things"* to *"http://domain.com/A/things"*.

But when I use the function reverse or the templatetag url,  the url will still be *"/A/things"* instead of *"http://A.domain.com/things"*

As we know,  django dispatch visits to views based on urls. I wonder if there is a way to make django dispatch visits based on domain?

Answer (score 1):

Look at django-hosts app. It provides very convenient work with subdomains.

https://github.com/ennio/django-hosts

Comment: I can recommend this app. Note that it *is* able to switch based on domain, not just subdomain - that may not be obvious from the readme.

Answer (score 0):

You could have different Django projects in differente VirtualHosts, another option would be to use the [Sites Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/)

Comment: I just want one database and one reposit,  So I decided to just use one django project  in different Virtualhosts.